# How writing to MemoryStream has changed in Delphi 10.2?

Tags: delphi, memorystream, delphi-10.1-berlin, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am porting my code from 10.1 to 10.2 and this gives me error:

```
procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
  CFourBytes: array[0..3] of Byte = (1, 2, 3, 4);
var
  LStream: TMemoryStream;
  LBuffer: array of Byte;
begin
  SetLength(LBuffer, 4);
  LStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  LStream.Write(@CFourBytes[0], 4); // E2036 Variable required

  LStream.Position := 0;
  LStream.ReadData(@LBuffer[0], 4);
end;
```

I had to change offending line to `LStream.Write(CFourBytes[0], 4);`

What has changed? Have I been doing it wrong for the whole time?

Comment: You have been doing it wrong all the time. <g>

Comment: Take a look at this (part of an article of mine): http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html#untypedparams

Comment: I remember that article :) It is still valid and good read Rudy! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in your question did compile in older versions, but it should not have done. The behaviour seen in 10.2 is correct.

What happens in old versions is very strange. The compiler selects this overload in `TStream`:

```
function Write(const Buffer: TBytes; Count: Longint): Longint; overload;
```

That is especially egregious because what has been passed to this method is the address of the static array `CFourBytes`. Which is categorically not a `TBytes` object.

Now it just so happens that a `TBytes` variable is the address of the first element of the array. And nothing in the `TBytes` override for `TMemoryStream.Write` refers to `Length()` of that bogus `TBytes` object. So your code happens to work as intended. This is very clearly a compiler error that has been fixed.

Your code has always been broken, you have just, up until now, been getting away with it by fortune. You should fix your code. Like this:

```
LStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  LStream.WriteBuffer(CFourBytes, SizeOf(CFourBytes));

  SetLength(LBuffer, LStream.Size);
  LStream.Position := 0;
  LStream.ReadBuffer(LBuffer[0], LStream.Size);
finally
  LStream.Free;
end;
```

Note that I am using `WriteBuffer` and `ReadBuffer` instead of `Write` and `Read`. These are the preferred methods to use with `TStream`. The reason being that they perform error checking and raise exceptions in case of errors, unlike `Write` and `Read`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps nothing has been changed.

`TStream.Write/Read` methods always used untyped `const/var` parameter  `const Buffer` ([help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TStream.Write)) and using address of variable is wrong (because method (to be exact - compiler) finds address of variable itself).

Probably you accidentally confuse these methods with Read/Write**Data** ones that use **typed** parameter and one of [overloaded versions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TStream.WriteData) gets `Pointer` type argument.

Here `ReadData` implementation dereferences this pointer and uses `Read` internally (`Read` in its turn calls `Move` and the last routine gets address of buffer again :) )

Comment: I am not using address of variable, I am using address of first element in array. This have worked in Delphi 10.1. Why 10.2 is returning me an error in compilation and 10.1 did not?

Comment: Using address of the first byte in `write` method is not correct. It was not correct ever. Simple example: `PByte  pb := @CFourBytes[0];  LStream.Write(pb, 4);` and check what you read (if AV does not occur). Are you sure that it is not allusion to dynamic arrays/strings usage like `PChar(@s[1])^`?  Could you show exact code that worked fine is Seattle?

Comment: We need to clarify some things: First, I was using 10.1 which is Berlin, not Seattle. Second: I gave you exact code that is perfectly working:)

I guess, it boils down to how code was interpreted by the compiler, it might be even a buggy behavior in 10.1 and it has been fixed in 10.2. That would explain why error is emitted during compilation in 10.2